# How to show multiple records on Line Chart in charts ReactChart?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, recharts

I am trying to show real time data with the help of react chart library known as Recharts.My chart description in link below.
https://recharts.org/en-US/api/LineChart
My data is in format like this.

```
[
  '950',   '70',    '94',    '155',   '155',
  '158',   '170',   '173',   '93',    '13',
  '65330', '64966', '64766', '64733', '64818',
  '64955', '65162', '65376', '54',    '299',
  '401',   '512',   '591',   '584',   '513',
  '438',   '407',   '311',   '195',   '136',
  '13',    '65491', '65476', '65416', '65409',
  '65382', '65415', '65448', '65419', '65448',
  '65477', '65483', '65480', '65477', '65477',
  '65500', '65486', '65483'
]
```

now i am receing this arrray after every 1ms.i want to draw 50 lines with 48 each point.After every 50 points .the first line should be neglected or remove and new lines start appearing.i hope you understand my question.

```
 import { LineChart, XAxis, YAxis, Legend, Line, CartesianGrid, 
Tooltip } from "recharts";
import { useState,useEffect } from "react";
const ShowGraph = ({ graphData }) => {
const [pts, setPts] = useState([]);
const [ptObject,setPtObject]=useState({})
 const data = [
 {
  "uv": 4000,

},
{
  "uv": 3000,

},
{
  "uv": 2000,

},
{
  "uv": 2780,

},
{
  "uv": 1890,

},
{
  "uv": 2390,

},
{
  "uv": 3490,

}
] 
useEffect(() => {
const dummyValArr = [];

for (let i = 0;  i <48; i++) {
  const dummyObj = {
    ...ptObject,
    "uv":graphData[i]
  };
  // console.log(`key1:${key11}\nkey2:${key21}\nvalue:${value1}`)
  setPtObject(dummyObj);
  dummyValArr.push(dummyObj);
}
setPts(dummyValArr)
},[graphData])
//  console.log(graphData[0]);
return (
<>
  <LineChart width={1000} height={500} data={pts}  margin={{ top: 5, 
  right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5 }}>
 
  

    <CartesianGrid stroke="#eee" strokeDasharray="7 7" />

    <Line type="monotone" dataKey="uv" stroke="#8884d8" />

  </LineChart>
</>

)

}
export default ShowGraph;
```

Comment: Is your dashboard component the topmost component?

Comment: Move the routes to app.js or some top most component.